# How to write a 301 redirect from an asp page to a php page in a htaccses file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This code is not responding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/index.asp?lang=he&cid=270$ /?aid=2260 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nor responding"? What _exactly_ happens? What do you see in your http servers log files? Is the interpretation of such dynamic configuration files enabled at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code made my redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=he&cid=270($|&)
RewriteRule ^/?index.asp$ /?aid=2260 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The code worked fine and when I added more references no longer worked, what could be the problem, I did not add contradictory rules

Answer (score 0):

The query string ("http get arguments") is *not* part of the URL when the rule pattern is compared against it. You need to use a separate condition to match it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QueryString} ^lang=he&cid=270$
RewriteRule ^/?index\.asp$ /?aid=2260 [R=301,L]
```

Also note the additional `?` near the start of the rules matching pattern. The URL is compared as *relative* (so *without* leading slash) in dynamic configuration files. The additional `?` makes that leading slash optional, so the rule now will work in dynamic configuration files ("`.htaccess`" style files) and likewise in the real http servers host configuration.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).